# Change UICollectionView's bounce start/end points

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, bounce

Normally UICollectionView starts to **bounce** when scrolled past it's contentSize, ie when `contentOffset < 0` or `contentOffset > contentSize.width` for horizontal orientation.

Is it possible to change this behavior so the bounce effect starts when scrolled past let's say 10th item (when `contentOffset < itemSize.Width * 10` or `contentOffset > contentSize.width - (itemSize.Width * 10)`)?

**UPDATE 1:**
@OverD - thanks for pointing me towards the right direction.

I ended up with some work in `scrollViewWillEndDragging` and adjusting `targetContentOffset` when necessary.

The problem I'm still facing is that the **bounce animation is not smooth** like the original bounce when reaching the contenSize end.

Any ideas what's missing? Code snippet below:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        let numberOfBouncingCells = 10
        let extraSectionWidth = (collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize.width + collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing) * numberOfBouncingCells

        let startXOffset = extraSectionWidth
        let endXOffset = collectionView.contentSize.width - 2 * extraSectionWidth

        let yOffset = collectionView.contentOffset.y

        if targetContentOffset.pointee.x < startXOffset {
            targetContentOffset.pointee = CGPoint(x: startXOffset, y: yOffset)
        } else if targetContentOffset.pointee.x > endXOffset {
            targetContentOffset.pointee = CGPoint(x: endXOffset, y: yOffset)
        }

    }
```

**UPDATE 2 (for answer):**

See answer below, I ditched the `scrollViewWillEndDragging` approach in favor of simply changing `collectionView.contentInset` `[.left, .right]`

Comment: I have never tried but I would think you would have to override scrollViewDidEndDraging method and create your own logic or bounce animation which is fairly simple to mimic or recreate

Comment: I think it'd be better to adjust your content size than trying to change the view's behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I've answered my own question eventually.

I only had to set `collectionView.contentInset` `[.left, .right]` to achieve expected behavior.

```
var collectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    return collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
}

let numberOfBouncingCells = 10
let extraBouncingWidth = (collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize.width + collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing) * numberOfBouncingCells

collectionView.contentInset.left = -extraBouncingWidth
collectionView.contentInset.right = -extraBouncingWidth
```